# Using jQuery val with AjaxToolKit's TextBoxWatermarkExtender with IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, cross-browser

I know, I know, "don't use AjaxToolKit"... but assume I'm stuck with it.

If I have the following:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textBox" />
<asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender runat="server
    TargetControlID="textBox"
    WatermarkText="Text" />
```

And

```
var textBoxSelector = $(#'<%= textBox.ClientID %>');
```

Then this does not work (i.e. that it changes the watermark text but not the desired text)

```
textBoxSelector.val('example text');
```

However I found this does in Chrome:

```
textBoxSelector.focus();
textBoxSelector.val('example text');
```

But not in Internet Explorer.

Any ideas how to implement this?

Comment: $('<%= textBox.ClientID %>'); needs to be $('#<%= textBox.ClientID %>');

Comment: Just a typo. Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set and use the behaviorid of the watermark extender itself.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textBox" />
<asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender runat="server
    TargetControlID="textBox" BehaviorID="textboxWaterMark"
    WatermarkText="Text" />
```

Then use `$find()` to access the object and `set_Text()`

```
var textboxWaterMark = $find("textboxWaterMark");
textboxWaterMark.set_Text('example text');
```

If `$find()` is returning null, you may have to wait until the page is loaded.  Not using jQuery, but using the toolkit

```
Sys.Application.add_load(MyFunction);
function MyFunction() {
    var textboxWaterMark = $find("textboxWaterMark");
    textboxWaterMark.set_Text('example text');
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly - my only amendment would be to give the `TextBoxWatermarkExtender` an `ID` then do `var textboxWaterMark = $find("<%= watermarkExtender.BehaviorID %>");`

Comment: That is so weird that you had to do that.  The purpose of the behavior ID is so that you don't have to use server tags to access it via javascript.  But, I'm not surprised.  the toolkit has always been a bit wonky.  Either way, glad it worked for you.

Comment: You don't _have_ to do that but it just means that if you change the `BehaviorID` for any reason (or you delete the control) then the ID will be updated or an error thrown accordingly.